# How can I hook into a function in Ultimate Member for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a check to a function in Ultimate Member:

```
function um_submit_form_login( $args )
```

You can find this function in this file here:

https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/blob/master/includes/core/um-actions-login.php#L202

In this function I need to add following check around the do_action:

```
$current_user_id  = get_current_user_id();
$encrypted_secret = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'encrypted_secret', true );
$verify_login_url = get_permalink( 1345 );
//If user has two way auth enabled redirect to verify auth page and skip login for now
if ( $encrypted_secret && ! empty( $encrypted_secret ) ) {
    wp_redirect( $verify_login_url );
    exit;
} else {
    do_action( 'um_user_login', $args ); //Do normal login if no two way auth enabled
}
```

So I did this in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'um_submit_form_login', 'two_way_auth_redirect', 10, 1 );
function two_way_auth_redirect( $args ) {
    $current_user_id  = get_current_user_id();
    $encrypted_secret = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'encrypted_secret', true );
    $verify_login_url = get_permalink( 1345 );

    //If user has two way auth enabled redirect to verify auth page and skip login for now
    if ( $encrypted_secret && ! empty( $encrypted_secret ) ) {
        wp_redirect( $verify_login_url );
        exit;
    } else {
        do_action( 'um_user_login', $args ); //Do normal login if no two way auth enabled
    }
}
```

But when I try it out it don't works. How can I implement this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear from your question since your link points to `um_user_login` function code, but looks like you want to extend `um_submit_form_login` function with your logic before it fires.

If you need to add your hook before default 
action 'um_submit_form_login', 'um_submit_form_login', 10 is called. 
I.e.

```
add_action( 'um_submit_form_login', 'my_um_submit_form_login', 1 );

function my_um_submit_form_login( $args ) {
    if ( /* your_special_redirect_required */ ) {
        wp_redirect( $verify_login_url );
        exit;
    }

    // if nothing special required - execution will continue and default
    // UM code called
}
```

But may be you want to change `um_user_login` functionality (to hook before login form posted), in that case you can do it similarly. i.e. via `add_action( 'um_user_login', 'my_um_user_login', 1 );`

Comment: I don't know why but this function don't gets called. I did it now directly in the plugin. I need to change this every update but I've wrote my changes to a text file so I can copy it back in if I need it.